# Writing a function for smoothing center values in specified range

Tags: javascript, calculus

I'm not sure this is the right place to ask this kind of question (maybe mathematica would be better ?).

I'm writing a program that reads input values from an analog joystick.

The values range from -100 to 100 with 0 being the center value.

My problem is, the stick values aren't very precise in the center area. For example, with the stick released, I should get an input value equal to 0 but I often get values like 2, 7, -5, etc (almost never exceeding 10 or -10).

What I'd like to do is applying a "smoothing" function to reduce the values around the 0 area.

I'm not experienced with mathematics and the best function I could find so far is:

```
function smooth(x)  {
    return Math.pow(x,3)/10000;
}
```

This gives me this kind of [values](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/ryxv42d5h6):

As you can see, this function is too "aggressive" because even f(20) ~= 0 !

Any idea of which better function I could use ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up mixing my first solution with the one provided by Nina.

```
var deadzone = 15;

function smooth(x) {
    return Math.abs(x) <= deadzone ? Math.pow(x,3)/Math.pow(deadzone,2) : x;
}
```

See [this](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/b8of0vpopt) graph

Answer (score 1):

You could check if the absolute value is smaller or equal to 10 and return zero instead of the value.

```
function smooth(x)  {
    return Math.abs(x) <= 10 ? 0 : x;
}
```

Comment: I thought of this solution but I'd like to avoid big gaps because with this function, smooth(9.99) = 0 while smooth(10)=10. I am looking for a more "progressive" approach